# WooCommerce Storefront - How To Customise The Product Catalogue And Reduce White Space?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront, hook-wordpress

I've recently been trying to enable a product filter in the left sidebar of my Woocommerce theme. In doing so I've found that the layout displays in a sub-optimal way.

[This image illustrates the changes I'm trying to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8A4J.png)

There is a lot of space to the left of the sidebar, I'm trying to get the sidebar to hug the left hand side of the browser window. There is also white space to the right hand side of the product catalogue. Again I'd like the catalogue to fill the space right up to the right hand side of the browser window.

I'd like to shift the "Clothing" header and the content below it up the page so that it sits in line with or just below the "Home>Clothing navigation".

I've been inspecting the code on the page and trying to make amendments to the CSS but I am having no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your active theme function.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'full_width_override');

function full_width_override(){
    echo '<style>.col-full{max-width:80% !important;}</style>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but it had no effect.